# База данных для мониторинга сети

Tags: c#, база-данных, ms-access

Добрый день! Прошу совета, делаю сейчас небольшую работу с БД, не могу определиться с инструментарием т.к нет конкретного опыта разработки с использованием БД.
Концепция примерно следующая, на C# будут работать два приложения. 
Первое будет считывать в потоках значение полей (IP Адресс/dns имен 600+ записей имя) и записывать в соседнее поле состояние и прочее. Второе приложение (назовем клиентское) будет просто считывать таблицы и разными фильтрами показывать отчеты, оповещать об алармах.
Есть небольшой опыт общения с Access, но как я понял таблицы в нем не могут одновременно использоваться для чтения/записи. Какую субд лучше использовать?

Comment: *как я понял таблицы в нем не могут одновременно использоваться для чтения/записи* Ну понял ты неправильно - могут. Хотя, конечно, Access для этого не сильно подходящая БД... Приложения будут работать в рамках одного хоста или разных?

Comment: С разных хостов

Comment: Под только что описанные ("никакие") требования подойдёт практически любая СУБД.

Comment: Согласен с комментарием выше. Сначала возьмите любую БД и реально упритесь в ее производительность.

Comment: @Семён Для вас сейчас главная задача не "какую СУБД лучше использовать"(ответ выше) а "как написать правильное приложение чтобы оно хорошо масштабировалось"

Comment: Ни в одной базе "не могут одновременно использоваться для чтения/записи". Нужно запись делать быстро. А если бросить таблицу открытой для записи (как это делает Access) - это не понравится большинству СУБД.

Comment: Возможно вам не нужна база данных (именно для 600 елементов). Массив на 600+ елементов (в вашем случае Dictionary) с# нормально справится и на чтение и на запись, и ни одна база его не обгонит по скорости. А база... только журнал писать.